# RopeGenerateAutoimportCache on vim startup

Tags: vim, python-mode, rope

I seem to have to run RopeGenerateAutoimportCache every time I open my python project in vim before RopeAutoImport will work. If I run RopeAutoImport before caching the projects modules I get the following error:

```
Global name my_func not found!
```

Is there a way of either generating the cache on each vim startup, or preferably, saving the cache to be reread on startup?

Comment: As a preliminary solution, you could add the line `RopeGenerateAutoimportCache` to the bottom of the file `~/.vimrc`. This will run that command once every time you start up Vim with `vim`. Though the command will also run when you edit non-Python projects with Vim, and that might cause errors.

Comment: Cheers Rory. I went back to python-mode and found a problem in the code for which, at the time writing this, I have a patch to be merged: https://github.com/klen/python-mode/pull/488 I am no longer seeing this problem with the patched code.

Comment: You should add your comment as a self-answer, so people know the question has been answered, and can easily read your answer if they find this question later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to python-mode (which is the suggested plugin for python) and found a problem in the code for which, at the time writing this, I have a patch to be merged: github.com/klen/python-mode/pull/488

I am no longer seeing this problem with the patched code.